# On software for ILP

Tags: mathematical-software, integer-programming

1. In 'Computational Experience with Lenstra's Algorithm' by L Gao, Y Zhang it is claimed that they have an implementation of Lenstra's fixed dimension integer programming algorithm. Is this available online anywhere?
2. Is Barvinok's algorithm available online?

Comment: Is this a right forum for such sort questions?

Comment: mathematical software is a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be of some help:

> De Loera, Jesús A., David Haws, Raymond Hemmecke, Peter Huggins, and Ruriko Yoshida. "A computational study of integer programming algorithms based on Barvinok's rational functions." *Discrete Optimization* 2, no. 2 (2005): 135-144.
>   ([Elsevier link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1572528605000198).)

For their comparisons, they used the [CPLEX MIP solver](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip/01_mip_title_synopsis.html),
and the software package `LattE`
available at https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/software.php.

Comment: I think it will help. So lattE implements Barvinok's algorithm? In spirit it has at least the same power as Lenstra's. Do you know what the complexity of Barvinok's algorithm is when employed for fixed dimension linear integer programming?

Comment: lattE implements more than that, in particular it can do ILP

Comment: @Turbo: The answer to your question may be in the paper I cited. Or you might write to DeLoera.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Does the software do Mixed ILP with Barvinok's algorithm?

Comment: It does ILP, see p.30 of the manual: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~latte/software/packages/latte_current/manual_v1.7.2.pdf

It does not do Mixed ILP, only "pure" ILP.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik ok thank you.. can Barvinok's algorithm be modified for mixed ILP?

Comment: apparently, yes, as a cursory look at http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.127.9460&rep=rep1&type=pdf
seems to suggest.